# centered social bar html & css

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a centered social bar, here the code:

HTML&CSS:

```css
.social-detail {
 color:#fff; 
    font-family: ProximaNovabold;
}
.icon-social {
    height: 50px;
    width: 208px;
 background: url(../../images/contact.png) center center no-repeat;
 float: left;
}
#social {
    padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    float: center;
}
#social li {
    height: 42px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    float: left;
}
#social .social-icon {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.social-info {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 198px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: ProximaNovabold;
}
```

```html
     <div class="social">
           <ul id="social">
                                <li>
                                                <div class="social-icon"><img src="http://rajawaliqq.com/app/img/images/icons/phone.png" title="" alt=""></div>
                                                <div class="social-info">
                                 
                                  <div class="social-detail">+123 456 789</div>
                                                </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="social-icon"><img src="http://rajawaliqq.com/app/img/images/icons/bbm.png" title="" alt=""></div>
                                                <div class="social-info">
                                
                                <div class="social-detail">1A2B3C4D</div>
                                                </div>
                                </li>
                                   <li>
                                                <div class="social-icon"><img src="http://rajawaliqq.com/app/img/images/icons/yahoo.png" title="" alt=""></div>
                                                <div class="social-info">
                                 
                                  <div class="social-detail">rakensu</div>
                                                </div>
                                </li>
                                
                                <li>
                                                <div class="social-icon"><img src="http://rajawaliqq.com/app/img/images/icons/skypee.png" title="" alt=""></div>
                                                <div class="social-info">
                                 
                                  <div class="social-detail">rakensu</div>
                                                </div>
                                </li>
                                      <li>
                                                <div class="social-icon"><img src="http://rajawaliqq.com/app/img/images/icons/facebook.png" title="" alt=""></div>
                                                <div class="social-info">
                                                        <div class="social-detail">rakensu</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                             </ul>
     </div>
```

and here the result:
[image: and here the result]

Comment: can you explain what you want to get? do you need the icons stay in the red area?

Comment: not in the red area but in centered

you also can visit for the real time here my link [website](https://www.gudanginternet.id/mayonnaise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve giving a fixed width, `padding: 0` and `margin: 0 auto`

```
ul#social {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

you can change the width to fit the icons...
delete the `float: center` property, it doesn't exist...

Comment: you are right I made a mistake in the css code, now it is correct.

Comment: tried to change but it doesnt work
you can visit my website to see [here](https://www.gudanginternet.id/mayonnaise/)

Comment: delete this at row 43 in your css:  #social {
    padding: 5px 0px 2px 0px;
    float: left; 
}

Comment: alright its worked thanks, tried to centered position like slider, but moves to far away, maybe i can handle that thanks alot bro

Comment: there are a lot of improvements you can apply... but I undestand you are new to this things

Comment: use a <div style="clear:both"></div> to break the float before the slider or use the display:inline-block for the <li> instead of float:left

Comment: could you check my website ? here the link [mywebsite](https://www.gudanginternet.id/mayonnaise/)

Comment: oh right i just checked, im using bootstrap as my front-end website, but the social bar isnt responsive as bootstrap, could you help me with that ?

Comment: have a look to the grid system in bootstrap, there's all you need... use .row class and the content centers itself

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your icons in a div thats is not affected by your background image:

```
<div class="social">
  <div id="centeringdiv">
    <ul id="social">

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and set that new div to "center"

```
#centeringdiv {
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: do you want the socials to be on the bottom?

Comment: check where your div is placed, i think it overlaps with more that just the social icons.

Comment: if possible make a https://jsfiddle.net/ of your code, its easier to see where it goes wrong

Comment: its not help, cant see if the icon was centered or not